# RouterLink with year month and day as parameter

Tags: angular

I need the following url in angular2

```
domain.com/2017-08-09/test
domain.com/2017-08-09
domain.com/2017-08
domain.com/2017

{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'test/:year-:month-:day/:slug', component: DetailComponent },
{ path: 'test/:year-:month-:day', component: DayComponent },
{ path: 'test/:year-:month', component: MonthComponent },
{ path: 'test/:year', component: YearComponent }
```

If above is possible is there a way how I can use them on routerLink?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Based on what I'am seeing on my question, it's already understandable what I want to achieve. I only want a routing way which allows the above url. The bottom part is the one that I tried. Now the only way I know in routerLink is to call them like these ['/test', item.year, item.month, item.day] etc, however the output is domain.com/test/2017/08/08. I just want to know if the above is possible and if yes, how I can use them in routerLink. Hope I answered you clearly.

Comment: You did, it's not that I don't understand the question, it's that you seem to have made no effort to answer it yourself. The bottom part shows the routes, but not the router *links*, which is what you actually seem to be asking about, so it's incomplete. And of course [x, y, z] maps to x/y/z, that's what the docs that you claimed to have read say, so why'd you try that?

Comment: I'm migrating an old application coded in cake php into laravel and angular 2 as the frontend. Basically what we need is to allow search engines to use the old url and still point them on the correct page on our site. That's why I'm trying to replicate the url I made on that old application. If not possible I need to look for another solution, thanks.